# как запустить OpenVPN в SSIS?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, openvpn, ssis

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запустить OpenVPN в пакете SSIS? У меня есть удаленная БД MySQL к которой я подключаюсь MS SQL Server через VPN-соединение которая создает программа OpenVPN. Раньше OpenVPN запускался вручную и подключение к базе отлично осуществлялось. Сейчас есть задача по расписанию выгружать данные из MySQL в мое хранилище MS SQL Server и для этого необходимо запуск OpenVPN добавить в интеграционный пакет SSIS. Кто может подсказать, как это сделать?

Comment: Сделайте bat`ник с запуском OpenVPN и внедрите его в пакет

Comment: Спасибо за наводку! Буду смотреть как его сделать.